# Wait for NSURLSessionTask to complete

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple NSURLConnection task

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url1!) { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
        return
    }

    let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    if parser.parse() {
        println(self.results)
    }
}
task.resume()

if task.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Completed {
    println("task is done")
}
```

But instead of an if statement, which is just passed right over since the task is still running when it hits that code, I wanted a way for code to run once "task" is completed. I can't seem to find anything in the literature.

Comment: I'm not professional, but was the link given about "reverseGeocode" as an answer to my question the correct link? Aside from being in Objective-C I can't see the relation.

Comment: The solution for any async method is the same. It doesn't matter that the link posted uses reverseGeocode as the example async method. The solution is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up all the time. You should put the code that you want to execute when the async task is done INSIDE the completion block.

Comment: What if you had multiple tasks with varying completion times and needed them all to finish before running some code?

Comment: @Tamarisk if multiple tasks  you need create an array 'taskArr'. when create a task add it to array 'taskArr'. If a task finist (hit completion block) remove it from 'taskArr'. when 'taskArr' is empty do some code you want after all task finish

Comment: Multiple async tasks can be coordinated with either dispatch_groups or NSOperation dependencies. Please see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1412859-adddependency

Comment: @larva, your approach is risky. Mutating an array from multiple threads can cause race conditions and even crashes. If you're going to do that you really need to either protect your array mutations and reads with lock, or dispatch all your array mutations to the main thread.